# String Comparison Logic Error

Tags: c, string, malloc

This program is to compare strings but i can't understand why it is returning same value of c everytime.Can anyone help me understand this?
Thank You.

```
 int func(char *n,char *m)
      {
           int c;
           c = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
           c=0;
           while(*n == *m)
               {
                    if(*n=='\0' && *m=='\0')
                        {
                            int c=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                           n++;
                           m++;
                        }
                  }
        printf("%d \n",c);
        return(c);
      }
```

Comment: Does this even compile?  You've got multiply defined `int c` within same scope, among other things.   Also, why are you casting the return of malloc()?.  In C, this is a mistake.

Comment: I'll better spare me the stnadard warning ("do not cast `void *`). You have worse problems to solve first. A good start would be a recent C book.

Comment: `c = (int)....`.... call the ambulance, please...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I just noticed that one. A good example to show if someone asks again why not to cast `void *`. Nothing is useless; it can always be used to scare someone.

Comment: Yeah,dunno how multiple use of int escaped me.But I read somewhere that variable scope gets destroyed outside the function, So used Malloc.       But didn't even thought for a second that return was only returning a value. My bad guys. Thanks to all

Comment: `[m|c|re]alloc()` is only necessary when allocating memory.  When you create `int c;`, the memory is created for that automatically on the ***[stack](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)***, no matter what the scope.  If you create `int *c`, then c = malloc(SOME_BYTES);` is necessary to create memory, and it will be placed on the ***[heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)***.  You _always_ must call `free()` for any variable that uses allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the intent is that the function returns
***1 for match***
***0 for mis-match***
The value of `c` is set to 1 as an indicator that the strings were equal, and returned upon either one of `m` or `n` being null. (if equal, both will be null)
If the strings were not equal, c is returned as initialized -> `0`.

***The version below*** does this.

Compare this version to your original for suggested changes:

1) you do not need to allocate memory for `int c;` it is implicitly created as an ***[auto](https://rakanalysis.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/variable-types-in-c-auto-static-register-and-external-a-brief-guide/)***.
2) you can initialize in the same line: `int c = 0;`
3) do not re-create `int c` in `if(...){...}`block
4) you want to exit if either `*m` or `*n` are NULL.
5) because the `while` guarantees *m & *n are same, do not need to check both for NULL. (thanks to @mch comment)

```
int func(char *n,char *m)
{
    int c=0;//1,2,
    while(*n == *m)
    {
        if(*n=='\0') //5, 4
        {
            c = 1;//3
            break;
        }
        else
        {
           n++;
           m++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n",c);
    return(c);
}
```

Comment: you can delete `|| (*m=='\0')`, because `*m` must be equal to `*n` because of the `while`.

Comment: @ryyker Thanks for Detailed explanation.Just started in C so making lots of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This function will always return 0.

You define `c` at the top and set it to 0 (the value returned by `malloc` is overwritten).  Later on, you define a new variable named `c` in an inner scope, hiding the previous declaration.  So the outer `c` is never modified after being set to 0.

Change `int c=1;` to `c=1` and that is probably what you're looking for.  Also, there's no need to call `malloc` here as that allocates dynamic memory and `c` is an `int` itself, not a pointer to one.

Comment: Hey Thanks.Newbie in C so silly mistakes here and there.